# Proof that there are arbitrarily large cardinal numbers using Cantor's theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I have already proved Cantor's theorem, which states that there is no surjection from a set $X$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$. A corollary to this theorem is that there are arbitrarily large cardinal numbers. I think the general principle is to take a set of some cardinality and consider its power set, which has "strictly larger cardinality." I'm not sure precisely how to notate this, however. Let's let $\kappa$ be some infinite cardinal. Does it make sense to talk about $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$? I don't believe it is, since $\kappa$ is a cardinality, rather than a set itself, so I can't say, for example, that $|\kappa| < |\mathcal{P}(\kappa)|$ or that $\kappa < \mathcal{P}(\kappa)$.

Is there a better way to formalzie this, or does this argument not work?

Comment: take a set with cardinality $\kappa$

Comment: How about $|X| < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$?

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi I considered this, but I wasn't sure if I could assert the existence of such a set and whether there was a better notation for it.

Comment: @Cardinality How do you understand the notion "$\kappa$ is a cardinality" if not as "there exists a set $X$ such that $|X|=\kappa$"?.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen this is a very good point. Thank you. Is it correct to say that a cardinal number "represents" a cardinality? So if $X$ has cardinality $\kappa$ and $|X| < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$, is it correct to say that the cardinal number representing the cardinality $|\mathcal{P}(X)|$ is strictly larger than $\kappa$?

Comment: If you define cardinals as equivalence classes of sets under the there-exists-a-bijection equivalence relation, then cardinals are uncomfortably large proper classes, but they are always by definition non-empty, i.e., for each cardinal, there exists a set of that cardinality. -- If you use the Axiom of Choice, you can reduce those uncomfortable equivalence classes to a nice representative, namely the smallest ordinal in that class. Then in particular every cardinality *is* already a set (and $|\kappa|=\kappa$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's state Cantor's theorem explicitly.

**Theorem** (Cantor). For every set $X$ we have $|X|<|\mathcal{P}(X)|$.

Given any cardinal $\kappa$, by Cantor's theorem we have $\kappa=|\kappa|<|\mathcal{P}(\kappa)|=2^\kappa$ which gives the conclusion.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this treats $\kappa$ as both a cardinality and a set. Is that the convention for cardinality numbers?

Comment: @Cardinality Every cardinal is a set, and clearly for every cardinal $\kappa$ we have $\kappa=|\kappa|$.

Comment: @Cardinality In $\mathsf{ZFC}$, each set is equinumerous to some ordinal, and the least such ordinal can be the definition of its cardinal, say $\kappa$, and then $|\kappa|=\kappa$. Without $\mathsf{AC}$, cardinals are in general [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Formal_definition) [differently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number), so $|\kappa|=\kappa$ will fail, but the argument [doesn't really need that anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_exponentiation).

Comment: @J.G. We usually work in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in the basic set theory.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to give some context.